# Default layout cakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, model-view-controller, ctp

I have a simple question , I am trying to use ONE default layout with header and footer to automatically show in other .ctp files when I make them, but for some reason I cannot do it and also I was thinking of using one javascript file to show in all the other pages as well , can someone give me with example on how to make the header and footer from one default file show up on all the other files.

Thank you for your help

Comment: the version is 2.6.2

Comment: As I know, you define `footer` and `header` inside your layout.ctp calling then like this: `<?php echo $this->Element('footer'); ?>`. Try to check then... Next, you can call your layout inside your `beforeSave` function in `AppController` like this: `$this->layout = 'layout';` . This will make sure all your pages load the `header` and `footer` content

Comment: You have a specific problem? or you just don't know how to do it? because using a layout in cakePHP is a straigth forward process. If you just need one layout, you don't even need to specify it in your controller, just place your `default.ctp` layout in your `app/views/layout/` folder, any .css or .js that you include in there will be in all your views

Comment: @YerkoPalma the thing is that I have a default.ctp with a footer , but for some reason there is another file i have sp.ctp but the footer isnt showing there thats the problem i have.

Comment: If you don't use that `sp.ctp` delete it. Your footer is an `element` or is part of your layout?

Comment: @YerkoPalma sorry I am new to cakePHP so i am asking way to many things , but i made the footer in cake php, like wrote the codes directly there, so its part of my default.ctp layout, so shouldnt it automatically show up in the sp.ctp, sp.ctp is another file but I want the footer to show up there as well , so what can i do to make it show up? I thought it automatically should.

Comment: So, your sp.ctp file is a view? where is it located? depending on the folder is how cakePHP will use the file. I'm a litle confused about your footer, is it on the `layout.ctp` or the `sp.ctp` file? what's exactly not showing?

Answer (score 1):

Here an example for your default.ctp

default.ctp

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- 
    //here your javascript yourscript.js 
    //It will be present in all your views.
    //the file has to be present in /app/webroot/js 
    -->
    echo $this->Html->script('yourscript');

</head>
<body>

    <!--
    //header
    //the file header.ctp has to be present in /View/Elements
    -->
    echo $this->element('header');

    <!--
    //here the content, for example from /View/Posts/edit.ctp
    -->
    echo $this->fetch('content');

    <!--
    //footer
    //the file footer.ctp has to be present in /View/Elements
    -->
    echo $this->element('footer');

</body>
</html>
```

$this->fetch('content') ist the "magic" part of CakePHP. Here will be fetched your view.

Comment: OP, this is the best option. Whatever items you need to re-use, create it as an "element". This way you can have a consistent header and footer that you can use in multiple layouts.